# Resetting single row values

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am using `smart-table` to display tabular data. One column of the table is editable. It is displayed and edited in an input field. Each row has a reset button which is supposed to reset edits made in the input field to the initial state.

How do I reset values of a single row (input field) when using `smart-table`?

Specifically what needs to be in the following function:

```
$scope.resetItem = function(index) {
  // .....
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about smart-table but why don't you try to get a copy of the data upfront and replace the related row with the original one?

```
var initialData = angular.copy(data);
$scope.data = data;
$scope.resetItem = function(index) {
  $scope.data[index] = angular.copy(initialData[index]);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, probably because `data` is an array and Angular doesn't do deep watching.  I have this: `$scope.resetItem = function(index) { $scope.rows[index] = $scope.rowsCopy[index]; }` where `rowsCopy` is copy of the original data, required by `smart-table`.

Comment: Well it looks like it's ok with regular angularjs: https://jsfiddle.net/ozanhazer/4ogafb19/

Comment: You added `angular.copy`, this makes all the difference

Comment: You don't have to extract index like this `var idx = $scope.users.indexOf(user)`.  Just use `$index` implicit property inside `ng-repeat`: `<button ng-click="resetItem($index)" class="btn btn-default">`